# Which PHP framework is easier to start

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy to use/learn PHP framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551162/easy-to-use-learn-php-framework)

Do most of professional programmers recommend using PHP frameworks? Which framework is relately easier to begin with? 
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy to use/learn PHP framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551162/easy-to-use-learn-php-framework) or [Simple PHP Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526040/simple-php-framework) and [lots more in the search...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=easy%20php%20framework)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please look at the `Related` section of this page (bottom right) to find you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an easier framework I will suggest Codeigniter. Its very easy learn, start and write applications in CI. Also it is very well documented. [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org) is another good framework which is easy to learn, but suffers lack of good documentation. Anyway its quite good to see that there is an active community around this framework. [Kohana unofficial wiki](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php) is a nice place to get started. You can find many other tutorials like [kohanaframework.blogspot.com](http://kohanaframework.blogspot.com) available online.