# Simple MVP example with PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, mvp

I know how to work with the **MVC** model, but I don't have an idea how to work with MVP. I read about the differences between them but don't know how to accomplish it.

Comment: Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference

Comment: Yes, but there is no example. Just a simple code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is twofold:

- view is passive and unaware of model
- presenter (controller) changes state of model, reads information and passes it to view

```
public function showUsers()
{
    // -- snip
    $data = $accountManager->getUserDetails($from = 10, $to = 20);
    $view->bind('list', $data);
    // -- snip
}
```

This would be a simplified example of presenter's method. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622038/727208) is an old answer, briefly explaining the differences between MVC-like patterns used in php.

Answer (score 0):

The MVP pattern is commonly used in event-driven development and evidently there are some PHP frameworks which supports this paradigm.  Here is another Stackoverflow question from a couple of years ago that may help get you pointed in the right direction:

[Does PHP supports MVP pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530023/does-php-supports-mvp-pattern)

Comment: MVP has nothing to do with event-driven paradigm. Here are few example of MVP frameworks, you might have heard of: Ruby on Rails, CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Yii.

Comment: The MVP pattern is "commonly" used with the event driven paradigm as it fits there.  Do I have your blessing now, Dr. tereško?

Comment: MVP is commonly (mis)used. Period. And since PHP was in the question tags, event driven paradigm does not really apply .. unless you see web sites themselves as inherently event driven applications.

Comment: And this is what has become of Stackoverflow.  Have a good day, bro.